# dynamically added last row not shown

Tags: android, json, android-layout, parsing

Guys am creating a table based on the json format

```
{"Seat Availability":[{"Ship":"Kavaratti","Departure Date":"10/12/2014"},{"Class":"Bunk","Seats":"178"},{"Class":"Bunk","Seats":"200"},{"Class":"Bunk","Seats":"214"},{"Class":"Bunk","Seats":"246"},{"Class":"First","Seats":"0"},{"Class":"Second","Seats":"112"},{"Class":"Second","Seats":"120"},{"Class":"Second","Seats":"95"},{"Class":"Second","Seats":"97"},{"Ship":"Kavaratti","Departure Date":"22/12/2014"},{"Class":"Bunk","Seats":"0"},{"Class":"Bunk","Seats":"1"},{"Class":"First","Seats":"0"},{"Class":"Second","Seats":"10"},{"Class":"Second","Seats":"19"},{"Class":"Second","Seats":"24"},{"Class":"Second","Seats":"6"},{"Ship":"Kavaratti","Departure Date":"03/01/2015"},{"Class":"Bunk","Seats":"229"},{"Class":"Bunk","Seats":"256"},{"Class":"First","Seats":"0"},{"Class":"Second","Seats":"105"},{"Class":"Second","Seats":"109"}]}
```

Everything is working except for the last ship details. I could not understand why the details of the last ship is not shown.

Here is the parsing code I used

```
        TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutProduct);


        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        result = "";
        JSONArray arr = null;
        try {
            arr = json.getJSONArray("Seat Availability");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        TextView heading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heading);
        heading.setText("Seat Availability: "+destination);


        for(int i=0,j=0,z=0; i<arr.length(); i++){      
            TableRow tbrow1 = new TableRow(HttpExample.this);
            TableRow tbrow2 = new TableRow(HttpExample.this);
            TableRow tbrow3 = new TableRow(HttpExample.this);

            tbrow1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C9D1F7"));
            if(i==0){
            TextView tv4 =  new TextView(HttpExample.this);
            tv4.setText(" Ship  ");
            TextView tv5 =  new TextView(HttpExample.this);
            tv5.setText(" Departure Date ");            
            tbrow1.addView(tv4);
            tbrow1.addView(tv5);
            }
            else{
                TextView tv3 =  new TextView(HttpExample.this);
                tv3.setText(" ");
                TextView tv4 =  new TextView(HttpExample.this);
                tv4.setText("  ");                  
                tbrow1.addView(tv3);
                tbrow1.addView(tv4);

            }

            TextView tv1=new TextView(HttpExample.this);
            TextView departure_date = new TextView(HttpExample.this);   
            TextView tv2 = new TextView(HttpExample.this);
            TextView index = new TextView(HttpExample.this);

            try {
                jo = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                result =  jo.get("Ship").toString();
                j++;
                tv1.setText(result+"  ");
                tv1.setEms(5);
                tbrow2.addView(tv1);                    
                result = (String) jo.get("Departure Date");
                departure_date.setEms(7);
                departure_date.setText(result+" ");
                tbrow2.addView(departure_date);
                i++;
                jo = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                TextView[] tv_heading = new TextView[9];
                TextView[] tv_value = new TextView[9];                              
                while(jo.has("Class"))
                    {
                    tv_heading[z] = new TextView(HttpExample.this);
                    tv_value[z] = new TextView(HttpExample.this);
                    tv_heading[z].setEms(4);
                    tv_value[z].setEms(4);
                    tv_heading[z].setText(jo.get("Class").toString()+" ");
                    seats = Integer.parseInt(jo.getString("Seats").toString());
                    if(seats==0)
                        tv_value[z].setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    else
                        tv_value[z].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#160A98"));
                    tv_value[z].setText(jo.get("Seats").toString());
                    tbrow1.addView(tv_heading[z]);
                    tbrow2.addView(tv_value[z]);                         
                    i++;
                    z++;
                    jo = arr.getJSONObject(i);      

                    }
                i--;
                z=0;
                TextView blank = new TextView(HttpExample.this);
                blank.setText(" ");
                tbrow3.addView(blank);
                ll.addView(tbrow1);
                ll.addView(tbrow2);
                ll.addView(tbrow3);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Please can any one point out the problem

Comment: `for(int i=0,j=0,z=0; i<=arr.length(); i++)` try this

Comment: ya tried it .. doesnt work though

Comment: Found out the problem.. It needed a break statement in the while loop if(i>=arr.length())break;

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem.. It needed a break statement in the while loop 
after i++
if(i>=arr.length())break;